# Store return value of function in variable in C

Tags: c, arrays, variables

I have a function, `average`, that takes an int array and int length and returns the average of that array. I want to call that from inside another function, `lessThanAverage`, that counts the number of items less than the average. I am trying to store the return value in a variable, but I am getting:

```
main.cpp:86:23: error: expected expression average=average(A[],length);
```

What am I doing wrong? I have only programmed in Java before so I'm not too familiar with C.

```
double average(int A[], int length) {
    double average=0.0;
    if(length!=0){
        for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
            average+=A[i];
        }
        return average/length;
    }else{
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Another function:

```
int lessThanAverage(int A[], int length) {
    int count=0;
    double average=0;
    average=average(A[],length);

    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        if(A[i]<average){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had two errors

1. `average` was both a function and a variable
2. You used `A[]` when passing A as an argument, should be `A`

Here is a working version:

```
int lessThanAverage(int A[], int length) {
    int count = 0;
    double avg = average(A,length);

    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        if(A[i]<avg){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**A scoping problem:**
The local variable, `average`, has the same name as the function, `average()`, in the parent scope.

**The Cause:**
The local variable `average` is 'hiding' the function `average()` in the parent scope.

**Explanation:**
When you declare a variable in a *child scope* with the same name as an *existing variable* or function declared in an enclosing scope, the existing variable will be 'hidden,' inaccessible, until the program exits the scope in which the local variable is declared.

**Example:**

```
double average() {
  //some code//
}

void compute() {

   //some code//

   int average;  // At this point, the function average is hidden.

   //more code//

}  // The block exits here, so variable average is no longer in scope,
   // and the function average is no longer hidden.
```